# EC2 instance reboot - instance ID does not exist

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto

I'm trying to reboot the remote instance:

```
ec2 = boto.connect_ec2(aws_access_key_id = key_id, aws_secret_access_key = access_key)
ec2.reboot_instances([instanceId])
```

and got the error `The instance ID 'i-xxxxx' does not exist`

Looks like I should connect to region - how can I get this value if the instance ID is the only input param?

Answer (score 1):

Credentials related information such as access key, secret access key and region should be configured outside of your code. This is to ensure portability.

The mechanism in which boto3 looks for credentials is to search through a list of possible locations and stop as soon as it finds credentials. The order in which Boto3 searches for credentials is:

1. Passing credentials as parameters in the `boto.client()` method
2. Passing credentials as parameters when creating a Session object
3. Environment variables
4. Shared credential file (`~/.aws/credentials`)
5. AWS config file (`~/.aws/config`)
6. Assume Role provider
7. Boto2 config file (`/etc/boto.cfg` and `~/.boto`)
8. Instance metadata service on an Amazon EC2 instance that has an IAM role configured.

If the script is itself running in an EC2 instance, the best practice is to rely on the instance metadata which will assume the IAM role.

Assuming you're calling the script from a local machine, the easiest way is to modify `~/.aws/credentials` by runing `$ aws configure` and specifying the region there.

read more: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

Is your instance in running state ?? try with this command :-

```
reservations = ec2_conn.get_all_instances(filters={'instance-id' : 'i-xxxxxxxx'})
new_instance = reservations[0].instances[0]
```